# Using a function in template literal

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I've been wondering why the following code does not work.

```js
const StyledComponent = styled.div`
  ${props => props.value === 'value' && function(parameter1)};
`
```

But the following does work:

```js
const StyledComponent = styled.div`
  ${props => props.value === 'value' ? function(parameter1) : function(parameter2)};
`
```

It looks like that's because the first one looks at it as a boolean it does not work. But then how about:

```js
const StyledComponent = styled.div`
  ${props => props.value === 'value' && `color: red;`};
`
```

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and clear problem statement. What does 'following code does not work' mean? It's unclear whether `props.value === 'value' ` is true or false in your case.

Comment: I can't recreate the non-working state of the first example. Can you expand it with an actual function and parameter that is not working?

Comment: **what** is it that you are trying to achieve? And what's the error message?